# JSON body is not deseralized by NancyModule

Tags: c#, .net, json, http, nancy

I have a route in my module that is supposed to accept a JSON body representing blog post. Problem is that the request body is not seralized. If I debug I see the following values on the request:

```
this.Request.Body.Length: 93
x.Keys.Count: 0
```

The route

```
Post["/Blog"] = x =>
        {
            var post = this.Bind<Post>(); //Breakpoint

            PostService.Save(post);
            return post;
        };
```

The HTTP-request

```
POST /Blog HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:57888
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "Post": { "Title":"Hello", "Content":"World", "Created":"2014-04-26" } }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Deserialization:

There's nothing wrong with your code, the problem is you've wrapped your JSON:

Your object has a property called `Post`, then it has the actual post.

Update your body to look like:

`{ "Title":"Hello", "Content":"World", "Created":"2014-04-26" }`

This most likely matches the properties on your `Post` object.

---

*Below is serialization to the client, not what the question was asking for*

---

### Serialization:

You need to add an `Accept` header.

I've written about Nancy Conneg here:

http://www.philliphaydon.com/2013/04/22/nancyfx-revisiting-content-negotiation-and-apis-part-1/

Your scenario doesn't work because you're only telling the server what your content is, not what you expect in return.

### Accept

Using the Chrome Plugin - Postman, you can test your scenario similar to this:

[image]

By applying the `Accept` header as `application/json` the content returned will be serialized.

### .json url

Alternatively, you can can add `.json` to the end your URL to return it as JSON:

`http://yoursite.com/blog.json`

This will force the JSON serializer to kick in.

### .AsJson()

If you want to always return JSON regardless, you can return your result using `.AsJson()`

```
Post["/Blog"] = x =>
{
    var post = this.Bind<Post>(); //Breakpoint

    PostService.Save(post);
    
    return Response.AsJson(post);
};
```

Note, if you're returning a `dynamic` type then you will need to cast it: `return Response.AsJson((object)post);`

Comment: I see now that my question was malformed. I meant DEserialization of a JSON body sent to the server. I want the JSON to be seralized into a Post object. According to the docs deserialization is triggerd by the Content-Type header, which I have so I must be missing something else.

Comment: Updated to the top of my answer.

Comment: The link to the blog post is broken. Try this:  http://www.philliphaydon.com/2013/04/22/nancyfx-revisiting-content-negotiation-and-apis-part-1/

Comment: Thanks @NorbertNorbertson I updated the link in the answer.